# I would like to create separate image folder based on registration id during register in php

Tags: php

**Here I want to create one more folder inside upload folder and that folder will be unique like based on registration id.**

In database I want to save path like ../upload/userid/image_name.jpg

> Here is my PHP code:-

```
session_start();
include 'db.php';
 $target_dir = "../upload/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);

        $uploadOk = 1;

        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file); 

        }

        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];

        $sql = "SELECT email FROM register where email='$email'";
        $qur = $connection->query($sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($qur)==0)
        {

        $password = md5($_POST["password"]);
        $phone = $_POST["phone"];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO register(name,email,password,photo,phone)
         VALUES ('$name','$email','$password','$target_file','$phone')";
        $success = $connection->query($sql);

        if (!$success) {
            die("Couldn't enter data: ".$connection->error);

        }else{
            echo "Thank You For registration <br>";

        }
        }else{
            echo "Email-id already exist";
        }
    $connection->close();
```

Comment: You've to create it yourself.

Comment: But I want to create when user registration. Because when I am fetching image from upload folder and there is multiple image with same name. So I want is save with unique folder inside upload folder

Comment: Check the answer please.

Comment: why not making the image name unique  with presetting the registrationId ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
if($uploadOk == 0){
 echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
}else{
mkdir($target_dir.$id);
//The variable $id is your registration id.
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$id."/");
}
```

Comment: creating folder with image name (I want to registration id of folder name) but unable to storing image inside this folder

Comment: @Chit By my code your image will be uploaded to ../upload/28192/image.jpg Isn't it working? Please, explain your problem.

Comment: Yes it is not working. Only it is creating folder as a image name.

Comment: @Chit I've written to make folder `mkdir("../upload/2772")` but not getting why it's making folder as image name.

Comment: It is making as image name only

Comment: @Chit I'm really sorry. Please, try now I've updated it.

Comment: Now I am unable to create folder as well as storing image. nothing is happening

Comment: @Chit It is may because your `target_dir` is containing `../`.

Comment: Ok but before It was creating folder

Comment: @Chit `../` means the parent folder. So, notice it.

Comment: Now I have tried with without ../ but not creating folder

Comment: @Chit Is your current php folder is the parent of `upload` folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php function mkdir("/path/to/my/dir"); You would need to move use of function move_uploaded_file after record has been inserted in database [in case of new registration]. After record is inserted you would need to get last inserted id from mysql  and use it in mkdir function with full path of the folder where you want to keep the uploaded file.